# Get Mysql data and split be delimiter

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, delimiter

I am Makeing a store. When user will purchase an item In Mysql database it will be added that they purchased product id 1 or 2 or both. Suppose a user purchases both (id 1 and 2) then i want the mysql column `purchases` of table `users` to show `1,2` , I can do that. But the main part comes that how can i get the result in PHP and separate the string by delimiter `,` in loop then get all the numbers separately and perform this:

```
//inside loop with $i incrementing till no more delimiter is found.

if($purchase[$i] == 1){
         echo 'You purchased '.$i.'';
}
```

Basically i want to store all purchased in `purchases` column in `users` separated by a comma then retrieve the result, separate the comma then compare each number in PHP.

PS. Noob here!

Comment: Don't use comma-delimited data in data base columns, it makes it really difficult to use them in queries. Put them in separate rows.

Comment: But to answer your question, use the PHP `explode()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad database design, you should create a table with a separate row for each purchase. But if you're stuck with this, use `explode()`:

```
$purchases = explode(',', $row['purchases']);
foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
    echo 'You purchased '.$purchase.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP explode function to get all values as an elements of Array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php